# Creating ProcessDefinition dynamically with Java in Flowable

Tags: java, bpmn, flowable

I am working to make `BPMN` using `Flowable`. I have created `ProcessDefinition` using `FlowableModeler UI`, but now my requirements have changed and I have to create these `ProcessDefinitions` dynamically using Java api.

I have search on it and found that we can do the same using `DynamicUserTaskBuilder()` but nothing on how to use it and achieve the dynamic  creation.
It would be a great help if someone can share a sample implementation or even a link of some article which explains how to achieve my target.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A Process Definition is created from a BPMN XML, by deploying those XMLs through the `DeploymentBuilder`. In case you want to programatically create them you will need to use `DeploymentBuilder#addBpmnModel(String, BpmnModel)`.

`BpmnModel` is the Java representation of a BPMN XML.